# Putting a process in the background without stopping it - (ctrl+z)?

Tags: linux, unix, process, job-control

If I start a process by typing it in normally at the command line, such as

```
wget http://site.com/bigfile.zip
```

and then decide I want to move that to the background, I know that I can use something like `ctrl+z` and then `bg 1` (or `jobs` first if needed to get the id) to put it in the background.

My question is if there is a way to move a job from the foreground directly to the background without stopping it - like another shortcut besides `ctrl+z` that would do that.

I also realize that I can append `&` to the end of the original command to start it in the background, but the question is in regards to when you start a process in the foreground and **then** realize you want to move it to the background.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, absolutely: [screen(1)](http://www.gnu.org/s/screen/) is the answer.

To get started, add `screen -R` to ~/.bash_profile or equivalent, log out, and log back in.

To continue what's running in the background, press Control-A then N. This will create a new terminal screen in the foreground while seamlessly continuing your running process on the background.

Press Control-A then " to get an interactive list of screens that you have open, or press Control-A then a number to switch directly to a specific screen.

Your original requirement was to be able to move a process to the background without stopping it. Screen has two additional benefits, and these are *huge* if you like to do multiple things at once:

1. You can switch between processes much more fluidly than by using Control-Z, bg, fg, etc.
2. If your terminal session gets disconnected, your processes (like `wget http://example.com/bigfile.iso`) will NOT terminate! All of your shell sessions will be there waiting for you when you reconnect.

For more information, read the [screen(1) manpage](http://linuxmanpages.com/man1/screen.1.php), or the [GNU Screen Manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/).

Comment: Just make sure you've got the `screen` package installed first :)

Answer (score 1):

`bg` starts a job that was stopped, and leaves it running in the background.
Basically `fg` and `bg` do the same, they resume a process, but `fg` does it in the foreground while `bg` does it in the background.

Just run `bg %(number of the job)` and you will have an output saying "runnning". 
If you check your jobs, you will see that your job is running and not stopped.